# React, why is setting the state as an array of undefined values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, state, setstate

My application takes the completed tasks from a Database, and stores them in the localstorage, every time someone performs another task, I update the status of the completed tasks, and the localstorage, however at a certain moment the values ​​inside the array become undefined, this is the function who update the state and localstorage

```
  const completeTask = useCallback(
    (data) => {
      data["event"] = eventID
      data["attendee"] = user._id

      const actionType = data.eventActivity
        ? data.eventActivity
        : data.exhibitor
        
      const taskData = tasks.filter((task) => task.key === data.name)[0]

      if (
        !completedTasks.includes(data.name + actionType) &&
        !completedTasks.includes(data.name) &&
        tasks && taskData
      ) {
        data["action"] = taskData.id
        data["points"] = taskData.points

        api.post("/api/gamification-log", { data: data }).then((response) => {
          
          localStorage.setItem(
            "Gamification:pontuation",
            JSON.stringify({
              logs: [...completedTasks, data.name + actionType],
              pontuation: prevPontuation + data.points,
            })
          )
          setUserPontuation((prevState) => prevState + data.points)
          
          setCompletedTasks((oldTasks) => [...oldTasks, data.name + actionType])
        })
      }
    },
    [eventID, user, completedTasks, tasks]
  )
```

It starts behaving the right way, and the completedTasks array looks like this

```
["visit_stand5eda6582e7c2deeb3cd09cf3","visit_stand5ebad3182e98903e662497ba"]
```

But after call this function some times the completed tasks array become this

```
["undefinedundefined", "undefinedundefined"]


**Update**

In the useEffect I was setting the state the wrong way, the problem is solved now
```

Comment: May you only include code relevant to the issue?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using stack overflow, but i believe all the function is important to understand the behavior

Comment: @ViniciusBass Does anything else in your code (not included here) call `setCompletedTasks` (for instance when props change)?

Comment: @DougNeiner in addition to this function, only useEffect calls setCompletedTasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say you don't pass a valid data variable or not a valid object.

for example: if `data.eventActivity` isn't set and `data.exhibitor` isn't set, the `actionType` will be `undefined`.

check the data you are passing to the `completeTask` funtion.

Comment: It makes sense, but why it sets all the values ​​of the array to undefinedundefined, even those that were already correct ?